# YUI3 DOM is undefined?

Tags: dom, yui, javascript, yui3

I am newcomer to Javascript and have been tasked with migrating our product's UI from YUI2 to YUI3.
It doesn't look like there's a migration guide anywhere, so I'm browsing internet posts and the yui docs for now.

In my global scope, I've temporarily added something like

```
var Y = YUI().use('*',function(Y){});
```

I've encountered a YAHOO.util.Dom.get(...) elsewhere which doesn't work with YUI3, and it looks like Y.DOM.byId(...) is the recommended migration. But, I'm getting the error that "Y.DOM" is undefined!

Whoever's using Y.DOM.(...), how did this get resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where you found the idea of `Y.DOM.byId`

Try

```
var node = Y.one('#elementID');
```

or if you want to use classes:

```
var nodes = Y.all('.className');
```

For more information on how to get nodes in YUI3, see their [documentation](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/node/)

EDIT:

```
<script>
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
    var node = Y.one('#elementID');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using YUI3 correctly?  It is quite different than YUI2.  I updated my answer to show the complete code you should be using.

Comment: Turns out it was a few import/dependency errors, and then I received what looked like some load-time-related errors...

After removing the global var Y = YUI().use(' * ',function(Y){}); and replacing YAHOO.util.Dom.get(...) with YUI().use('*',function(Y){}).one(...)._node, everything seemed to load fine...